# Counting how many times I've divided with recursion

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment where I need to find how many times I need to divide to reach 1 or less(n), and then add 1 to that number(n). I've got it all setup but I cannot figure out how to add the 1 at the end, for example; if I enter 20 I should get 6, but my code outputs 5.

```
def divisions(n): 
  if n <= 1: 
    return 1
  return divisions(n // 2) + 1
n = input("Enter a number:")
print divisions(n)
```

Comment: It's high time to switch to Python 3. Python 2 is almost at the end of its life.

Comment: `print divisions(n) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The right solution should be 4:

If you want to obtain 1 from 20, you need to divide by 2 *4 time*:

```
20//2 = 10 #1
10//2 = 5 #2 
5//2 = 2 #3
2//2 = 1 #4
```

You recursive function should be as such:

```
def divisions(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0 # here
    return divisions(n // 2) + 1
n = input("Enter a number:")
print(divisions(int(n))) # here you need to do a cast from string to int
```

Without using the `//` operator (`//` is unconditionally "flooring division") the right solution should be 5:

```
20 / 2 = 10.0 # 1
10.0 / 2 = 5.0 # 2
5.0 / 2 = 2.5 # 3
2.5/ 2 = 1.25 # 4
1.25 / 2 = 0.625 # 5
```

Comment: `20` gives you another `+1`.  It should be `5`.  It's not clear where OP gets `6` from though.

Comment: hum, I think it should be 4 . Check again my answer @huck_cussler. Now it should be more clear

Comment: As of your edit, you are now ignoring the `1` that gets returned in the base case (`n <= 1`).

Comment: Yes @huck_cussler, what I am saying is that the *right* solution should be 4. Not what the actual recursive function does now